# How to limit number of files uploaded with plupload integrtion module?

Tags: forms, files

I'm using [Plupload integration](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) module. In my Form API form I want to use it as simple replacement for file element. However, both `file` and `managed_file` types accept one file. `plupload` accepts any number of files. How to limit it to only defined number of files? Or simply one?

Setting cardinality as [FileField Sources Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload) does:

```
'#plupload_settings' => array(
  'cardinality' => 1,
```

does not work, and I wasn't able to find any other parameter for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I limited it to single file, was to create js file and attach it to the form. In that file, I bound a function to `QueueChanged`, to remove excess files and hide "Add file" button:

```
(function($) {

Drupal.plupload = Drupal.plupload || {};

/**
 * Attaches the Plupload behavior to each Plupload form element.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.download_plupload = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $(".plupload-element", context).once('download-plupload-init', function () {
      var add_button = $(this).find('.plupload_button.plupload_add');
      var uploader = $(this).pluploadQueue();
      uploader.bind('QueueChanged', function() {
        var local_uploader_element = this;
        // Remove files exceeding the cardinality setting.
        if (local_uploader_element.files.length >= 1) {
          var i = 0;
          for (i=0;i<local_uploader_element.files.length;i++) {
            if (i >= 1) {
              $(this).removeFile(uploader.files[i]);
            }
          }
          add_button.hide();
        }
        else {
          add_button.show();
        }
      });
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

This is a simplified version of js found in [FileField Sources Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload), trimmed, without Field API specific parts, and made to work on all plupload elements.